# CSS document height on mobile device

Tags: css, html, mobile

Ok so my page display as expected in browsers on my PC. However when i load my page on a mobile device, for some reason, the document `height` is not 100%

I have read on it and a lot of them suggest to set the position to absolute. I cant do that in my case because i use divs to get my page centered.

It seams like my mobile device load the page height based on its content instead of actual css values.

my body height and all other containers are set to 100%

The footer is set to bottom 0. But 0 ist not the bottom of the screen on my phone its more like the length of the content. I have tried adding

```
echo ' <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height initial-scale=1">';
```

but it still the same.

**Update:**
Ok its seams like what i was seeing on my phone was not to scale. It was set to fit the screen width but the height was not adjusted to that scale. So no mater what scale im using the height setting will remain. I will try to use the fixed property to my footer and keep you posted.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed `,` after height property.
Change

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height initial-scale=1">`

to

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it to display nicely using a 0.4 scale now i wonder how it looks on anothe phone.

Comment: You are welcome. You should check it on other devices.